# Determine if equation will generate perfect squares

Tags: diophantine-equations, quadratics

Given the following quadratic equations:

- $4n^2 + 128n - 131$
- $4n^2 + 16n - 11$
- $4n^2 + 24n - 3$

Is it possible to determine how many values of n will generate a perfect square?  Or better yet, is it possible to determine which values of n will generate a perfect square?

Comment: Do you need it specifically just for those 3 equations? Or will you need a general method for any of the form?

Comment: Here you can complete the square, set the quadratic equal to an unknown $m^2$, rearrange and factor, $$(2n+a+m)(2n+a-m)=b,$$ then look at the prime factorization of $b$ and check when $k=(d+b/d-2a)/4$ is an integer for not-necessarily-positive divisors $d|b$, in which case $n=k-a$ and $m=\pm(2k+a)$.

Comment: @RagibZaman I needed a general method for any equation of the form 4n^2 + 4kn - p.

Comment: @anon Could you provide an example using one of the equations I gave?

Comment: I mistyped above, it should read $n=k$ and $m=\pm(d-b/d)/2$. I'll take the last one as an example. Complete the square for $4(n+3)^2-39$, then equate to $m^2$ and obtain $$(2n+6+m)(2n+6-m)=1\cdot3\cdot13.$$ For $4|(d+39/d-12)$ we can use $d=1,3,13,39$ or their negatives, which gives $n=1,7,-13,-7$ corresponding to squares of $m=\pm5,\pm19$.

Comment: For $4n^2+4kn-p$, it is, as the answers make clear, straightforward. Complete the square to get $(2n+k)^2-k^2-p=y^2$, and rewrite as $(2n+k-y)(2n+k+y)=k^2+p$.  Then we get all solutions by factoring $k^2+p$.  But note for example that if we change the $4n^2$ to $3n^2$, things get **very** much harder.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm not sure how to mark comments as an answer, so I'll mark everything I can. This really helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can complete the square.  For the third example, $4n^2+24n-3=(2n+6)^2-39.$  As $(n+1)^2-n^2=2n+1$, this cannot be a perfect square for any $2n+6$ greater than $20$, leaving only $7$ possibilities.

We can do better.  You want $(2n+6)^2-39=p^2.$  This means $39=(2n+6-p)(2n+6+p)$.  There will be one solution for each way to factor $39$ into two numbers.  Because of the $2n,$ you need the sum of the numbers to be even, which will be true for odd numbers like $39$ and will be the case for your other three examples.

Answer (score -4):

**HINT:** Let's rearrange the first equation:

$4n^2-4n+132n+1-132=(2n-1)^2+132(n-1)=m^2$ now we can easily see that $n-1$ has to be $0$ so $n=1$

For the second equation we may write:

$4n^2+4n+12n+1-12=(2n+1)^2+12(n-1)=m^2 \Rightarrow n=1$

For the third equation:

$4n^2+20n+4n+25-28=(2n+5)^2+4(n-7)=m^2 \Rightarrow n=7$

Comment: For the first, n=81 works as well.  For the third, n=1 works.

Comment: @Ross,I didn't say that these solutions are unique

Comment: That is implied by the fact that "now we can easily see that $n-1$ has to be $0$"

Comment: and how is that a hint?